# Equation for the average of a known quantity of numbers

Tags: average

How would one express this in the form of an equation?

> The average of 500 numbers, each of which are between 2 and 50, is 7.5

And can it be graphed?

Comment: $\sum_{i=1}^{500}\frac{n_i}{500}=7.5$ where $2\leq n_i\leq50$  OR 

$$\sum_{2\leq n_i\leq50}_{i=1}^{i=500}\frac{n_i}{500}=7.5$$

Comment: $i,n_i \in \mathbb N$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\frac{1}{500} \sum_{k=1}^{500} x_k = 7.5$ and $x_k \in [2,50]$ for any $k \in [1..500]$.

The only reasonable way to display it graphically is to plot the points $(k,x_k)$ for each $k$, and draw two horizontal lines for the lower and upper bounds, and another horizontal line to denote the average. You can do this easily using any spreadsheet software.